# Zipping font files (e.g: ArialMT.ttf) with JSZip is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jszip

Zipping images and HTML files works fine but when adding the font file for the CSS; the font file is 1kb in size and can't open.

I've tried to just zip the font without any other files and still the same problem.

```
let zip = new JSZip()
let imageURLCount = 0
let fontFileCount = 0

let imageURLs = [
 'http:site.com/image1.jpg',
 'http:site.com/image2.jpg',
 'http:site.com/image3.jpg',
 'http:site.com/image4.jpg'
]

let fontFiles = [
 'http:site.com/fontFile1.ttf',
 'http:site.com/fontFile2.ttf',
 'http:site.com/fontFile3.ttf',
 'http:site.com/fontFile4.ttf'
]

// zip images
imageURLs.forEach((url, i) => {
  JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, (error, data) => {
     if (error) {
        throw error
     }
     // zip file name
     imageFileName = 'image_'+i+'.jpg'

     // create images folder
     zip.folder('images')
        .file(imageFileName, data,{binary: true})

     imageURLCount++
     if (imageURLCount === imageURLs.length) {
        zipComplete(imageURLCount,fontFileCount)
     }
  })
}) // end imageURLs[] forEach 

// zip font files
fontFiles.forEach((fontFile, i) => {
  JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(fontFile, (error, data) => {
     if (error) {
        throw error
     }

     // zip file name
     fileName = 'font_'+i+'.ttf'
     zip.file(fileName, data, {binary:true})
     fontFileCount++
     if (fontFileCount === fontFiles.length) {
        zipComplete(imageURLCount,fontFileCount)
     }
  })
}) // end fontFiles[] forEach 

// PS: zipComplete(imageURLCount,fontFileCount) checks if both arrays looped to the end and then trigger the 'file-saver' SaveAs()
```

How would I go about zipping the fonts or is it not possible to zip fonts with JSZip?

Comment: Did you check that the variable `data` actually held the font binary data and not something else, for example html of an error page in the case the urls were not valid or 404'ed?

Comment: Inside `imageURLs.forEach((url, i) => {})` zip is never constructed. Are you missing code from your example?

Comment: @PatrickEvans when I console.log(data) I get: 
`ArrayBuffer(97344) {}
[[Int8Array]]: Int8Array(97344) [79, 84, 84, 79,  …]
[[Int16Array]]: Int16Array(48672) [21583, 20308, …]
[[Int32Array]]: Int32Array(24336) [1330926671, -2147480320, 2157312, …]
[[Uint8Array]]: Uint8Array(97344) [79, 84, …]
byteLength: (...)`

Comment: @BlueWater86 sorry I missed that part (added it now). It's strange that I can zip images, text, remote server HTML,CSS and JS but not the fonts. It's a massive function so I just wanted to show that the images and fonts "zipping" was approached in the same way instead of pasting the whole thing. cheers!

Comment: Could it be that the zip function SaveAs() run before all the font data got loaded?
How are you loading the fonts? XHR?

Comment: @moonunit7 - Yes, I'm using xhr and even added a massive setTimeout() to make sure it doesn't run too soon. Odd that everything zips fine except the fonts. So I'm wondering if font files need a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expected to edit your sample and find a problem in your code but it turns out that nothing is wrong. Here is a working example that successfully zips a .ttf file & then downloads the zip.

I would guess that the problem lies in the content that is being returned from your .ttf URIs.

```js
let zip = new JSZip()
let imageURLCount = 0
let fontFileCount = 0

let imageURLs = []

let fontFiles = [
  'https://fontlibrary.org/assets/fonts/symbola/cf81aeb303c13ce765877d31571dc5c7/7d8d51a2e1b57d59075325384458fac6/SymbolaRegular.ttf'
]

// zip font files
fontFiles.forEach((fontFile, i) => {
  JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(fontFile, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }

    // zip file name
    fileName = 'font_' + i + '.ttf'
    zip.file(fileName, data, {
      binary: true
    })
    fontFileCount++
    if (fontFileCount === fontFiles.length) {
      zipComplete(imageURLCount, fontFileCount)
    }
  })
}) // end fontFiles[] forEach 
function zipComplete(imageURLCount, fontFileCount) {
  zip.generateAsync({
      type: "blob"
    })
    .then(function(content) {
      // see FileSaver.js
      saveAs(content, "example.zip");
    });
}
// PS: zipComplete(imageURLCount,fontFileCount) checks if both arrays looped to the end and then trigger the 'file-saver' SaveAs()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.2.2/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip-utils/0.1.0/jszip-utils.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/filesaver.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks! that gives me hope :) At least I know know that the problem is not JSZip. Should have ran the code outside the project like you did ‍♂️